# Norwegian letters in SOLR autocomplete

Tags: solr

I have a autocomplete index that translates norwegian letters into its international counterpart, eg æ is translated into ae in the result set. How can i make it return the norwegian letters instead?

It can be tested here by typing "eksot" https://norecopa.no/search The second result will be "eksotiske kjaeledyr" which should have been "eksotiske kjæledyr"

This is the definition of the index:

```
<fieldtype name="suggest_phrase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="(^[^A-Za-z0-9]*|[^A-Za-z0-9]*$)" replacement=""  replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="60" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="7" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="99" outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

And this is the component and respuest handler:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="field">text_sug</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
        <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">text_suggester</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store the Norwegian characters in the index and let the autocomplete function translate the international representation back to Norwegian? I fear that solr server only returns what's in the field.

Comment: Any reason why you're translating the Norwegian letters to ascii-versions for the auto complete field? If you don't want the translation to happen, define a separate field that does not perform the translation? (Solr handles all Norwegian letters just fine, and I'd suggest using a different stemmer than the English one, but that might depend on what results you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You are using TSTLookupFactory, which is the simplest implementation. There are [several more](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester#Suggester-LookupImplementations).

One of them, AnalyzingLookupFactory, has an additional analysis step using a separate field type. I believe that if you move your character-mapping into that step, you will be matching on ascii representation but returning the original value.